# When was KNOX efuse introduced?

Tags: rooting, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-j7

I realy want to root my samsung j7 (2016) phone and flash custom roms on it.
I know it has knox but i am not sure is it the one that can be reversed by triangle away app or it is efuse that can not go back.

Can somone tell me what was the first phone with KNOX efuse or when samsung introduced efuse. Also if you are not sure about answer you are giving please tell that.

Comment: Since I'm not sure, I'll just leave a comment: the I9300, Exynos variant, had no KNOX, but the I9195 did, so sometime between the abovementioned's release dates.

Comment: Knox e-Fuse started appearing late 2014 in high end models and all models by late 2015... Although I can't say for sure, chances are good your device has has e-Fuse.

Comment: That sounds bad...

Comment: I saw a post stating that you can short circuit e-fuse under memory ship but i am not sure if phone will survive next knox attempt to destroy fuse